# Can a firewall blocking a guest virtual machine secure the host?

Tags: firewalls, virtualization

I have searched up whether a host is safe from its guest, and generally, it is said that, aside from vendor security flaws, a guest that is infected can infect the host over a shared network.

So, what if a firewall is set up to block all traffic from the guest to the host?  You don't need to be on the network to control the guest, as far as I know. So... since the guest can't access the host over the network, is the host safe?

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways by which a corrupted/evil guest VM may hurt its host:

1. By talking to the host over the network; this is similar to having an evil machine on the same LAN as the host, although there can be details, depending on how networking works in your particular VM.
2. By "escaping" the virtualization layer, a successful escape granting (for instance) read/write access to the VM process on the host, or hypervisor hijack, or anything of the same level.

The second way is what "vendor security flaws" are about. If the VM implementation is secure, then it ought to prevent such occurrences.

Firewalls act on the network side of things, so that is relevant for the first way only. However, if you are working with potentially hostile VM, then you must, indeed, do something about network-based attacks, and that may involve firewalls.

**In a typical VM**, the host provides network services to the guest. These services are configurable. For instance, if you look at what [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) provides, then the guest may:

1. have no network at all (the VM engine does not provide the guest with a virtual network interface);
2. have a network interface linked with other VM under the same engine, but separate from the actual Internet;
3. have a network interface linked with other VM *and with the host*, but otherwise separate from the Internet;
4. have a network interface that the host sees, and for which the host provides NAT service (but this does not correspond to an actual ethernet card on the host).
5. have a bridged network interface, allowing the VM to send and receive ethernet frames as if it was another physical machine connected to the LAN.

In the first two cases, the VM cannot talk to the host and that's final. In the cases 3 and 5, the VM can talk to the host through what the host sees as a network card (a new, software-based card in case 3; its actual physical card in case 5). In case 4, the host OS does not see the packets from the guest as packets; they are array of bytes in the VM engine process, but that process translates them as connections to other machines, which may be the host itself.

Firewalls have nothing to do with cases 1 and 2. A firewall *may* work with cases 3 and 5, albeit on distinct ethernet interfaces; beware that in those cases the hostile guest sends arbitrary *ethernet frames*, which may not necessarily show up on the link as relevant to the IP address you believe the guest should use. You should handle these situations in the same way as you would for an hostile machine linked to the LAN -- if you prefer, assume that your host is on an open WiFi in a fast food restaurant. For case 4, firewalls are irrelevant, because any connection to either the host or any other machine will appear to the host OS to come from the VM engine process itself.

The above is about what happens with Virtualbox; details may vary with other virtualization solutions.

Comment: So, in terms of case 3 and 5, if the firewall blocks the evil virtual machine's IP address, all the evil vm has to do is spoof its IP address and the firewall protection against the vm is rendered useless?  Is there any way to completely close off connections to the host?

Comment: If you close off the complete network for the guest, then the VM will be isolated, and, in particular, won't be able to talk to the host. The tricky point is about allowing the guest to talk to the rest of the world but _not_ to the host itself.

Comment: Would segmenting the LAN to isolate the VM work?  As in, place the VM in its own LAN segment, isolated from the host?  I'm doing research on the fly, by the way, so I'm piecing together information as I go, so if there's anything wrong about my understanding of things, please correct me.

Comment: @Will You could add a pfSense VM running a client for a VPN service. Attach that VM's LAN interface to a VirtualBox internal network that's shared with your "hot VM". It will have Internet connectivity, but no direct network connectivity with the host.